# Install Ubuntu on Windows 7 tablet

Tags: system-installation, windows-7, ubuntu-touch, hp, tablet

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Windows 7 tablet (HP Slate 500). I wanted to install Ubuntu touch, but can't seem to find an .iso anywhere. The guide here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/ does not help as it is not an Android tablet.

I was going to use Unetbootin and put it on a USB and install it from there. However, I'm afraid if I download the desktop version, I won't be able to type anything in the tablet.

I'm doing this for educational purposes. The tablet is really old and doesn't have anything important in it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Ubuntu touch for this device (that I could find).

You should look at [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) as your CPU is weak, it comes with an on-screen keyboard, find it in `Applications > Universal Access > Onboard Settings`, so no worries there, on the log in screen you will see the accessibility icon ( a little man symbol) and can start the keyboard from there.

Also any usb keyboard will work too.

If your tablet is old and not important, whats wrong with just trying some distros ? If something won't work, try a different one.

UPDATE: This may be of interest to any x86 tablet users.

There is actually a early daily build of [Ubuntu Touch 15.10 (Wily Werewolf)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/) on ubuntu.com, can't say how well it works, it is a daily.

Looking at the tablet in this question, it should meet the requierments for running Touch.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It's actually my friend's tablet and he wanted Ubuntu. I'm still going to try other distros now though. I put xubuntu on my usb with unetbootin; however, after I change the boot order on the tablet it doesn't boot into the usb. Very quickly it says "Missing Operating system". If you can provide any information on that, it would be great. Either way, thank you for everything!

Comment: If the answer is good for you please accept it, did you use a windows PC to make the USB, if so try making one with this http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ and try again

Comment: I am on Mac, used Unetbootin. I formatted the USB to MS-DOS (FAT).

Comment: I would recommend opening a new question something like "Missing Operating system when trying to install xubuntu on X86 tablet". Mention the Mac and Unetbooting, I don't own a mac so im not that knowlageable about them, but first try this, it is how to make an ubuntu usb on mac without 3rd party app, has loads of steps, defiantly worth a try. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx